# Code in VBA loops and never ends. How to fix this?

Tags: vba, excel

I run this code to delete rows which have have > -100.
However it keeps looping and never stops.

What am I missing here?

```
For i = 2 To 500
If Worksheets("Sales").Cells(i, 3).Value > -100 Then
   Worksheets("Sales").Cells(i, 3).EntireRow.Delete
   i = i - 1
End If
Next i
```

Comment: Remove `i = i - 1`? You want to use a different variable. Edit: or go backwards (bottom to top).

Comment: In addition to what @findwindow said, change the loop to go backward `For i = 500 To 2 Step -1`

Comment: @findwindow there are cases that i need to delete two rows the one after the other, thats why i put i = i - 1. so i want to check all the lines

Comment: That's why you should go backwards when deleting.

Comment: Going backwards will take care of that, without the i - 1. because as you delete the lines only the ones below change not above so you are always going to the proper next line.

Comment: Just logically, it's silly to have a loop that increments `i` only to decrease it within the loop XD Running on treadmill ^_^;

Comment: The big problem is that a blank cell returns a value of 0, when you get to the bottom of your data because you deleted lines, there is a lot of blank cells to still go through. So because it returns 0 which is greater than -100 it just keeps deleting and resetting i to i -1.  this will loop forever.

Comment: @ScottCraner's last comment is really what highlights your problem. Theoretically what you had done could have worked, even though your method would be inadvisable (as pointed out further above) - if only you checked to see if a cell was not blank as well as < 1. Your theory was sound, but always be wary of how Excel treats blank cells - usually not in the way you'd like.

Answer (score 8):

Maybe you could union the rows and delete them at once? Something like this (untested).

```
Dim myRow As Range
Dim toDelete As Range

For i = 2 To 500
    If Worksheets("Sales").Cells(i, 3).Value > -100 Then
       Set myRow = Worksheets("Sales").Rows(i)
       If toDelete Is Nothing Then
            Set toDelete = myRow
        Else
            Set toDelete = Union(toDelete, myRow)
        End If
    End If
Next i

If Not toDelete Is Nothing Then _
    toDelete.Delete
```

Comment: While this is perhaps a bit more complex than going backwards in this case, this method does lead to advantages sometimes. For example, using a method such as "For Each cell in Range..." precludes one from a simple "For i = 10 to 1 Step -1" solution. Also, when deleting, it can sometimes be better to add your to-be-deleted items to a list, prior to actually doing so.

Comment: And maybe to delete all at once is faster am I right?

Comment: Yes. I 2nd @Grade'Eh'Bacon's comment. Crafty solution to the problem, even if a bit more complex.

Comment: actually, the fastest way to do it would just be to filter on values `> -100` and delete all the visible cells.

Comment: Looping is such a common exercise in coding. Amazing there isn't a "best" way.

Comment: @ScottH I guess to use filter would be the fastest way indeed!

Comment: or sort, delete block (find first) and resort with line number

Answer (score 7):

When deleting or inserting rows in VBA you need to start with the **last** row and move toward the **first**, since any given row will get lost in the loop once it's deleted or new rows are inserted.

See the code below:

```
For i = 500 To 2 Step -1
     If Worksheets("Sales").Cells(i, 3).Value > -100 Then
        Worksheets("Sales").Cells(i, 3).EntireRow.Delete
     End If
Next I
```

### EDIT

I just thought of this as well, which will run much faster (especially if you had a lot more than 500 cells):

```
With Worksheets("Sales")
     'assumes row 1 is headers
     .Range("C1:C500").AutoFilter 1, ">-100"
     .Range("C2:C500").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete
     .AutoFilterMode = False
End With
```

Comment: Both are good options - using autofilter is a good example of reducing one's own coding by maximizing the utility of Excel itself. If the data is already on a worksheet, there are likely some worksheet-oriented functions which are faster than treating the data as a 'regular' array.

Comment: Using the AutoFilter to delete rows not necessarily will be faster it will depends on the number of areas the auto filter range of visible cells has.