# Code not deleting every non numeric row

Tags: excel, vba

I have this code here which looks through a column of numbers, colors the cells with numbers and deletes the cells and its corresponding rows if it's a nonnumeric entry(the cells are filled with "-"). It deletes some of the non numeric rows but not all of them.

```
Dim wbI As Workbook, wbO As Workbook
    Dim wsI As Worksheet, wsO As Worksheet
    Dim iCounter As Long
    Dim iCounter1 As Long
    Dim iCounter2 As Long
    Dim lrow As Long, rw As Long
    Dim OutLookApp As Object
    Dim OutLookMailItem As Object
    Dim MailDest As String
    Dim subj As String
    Dim bod As String
    Dim lastrow As Long
    Dim lastrow1 As Long

 lastrow = wsI.Cells(Rows.Count, 4).End(xlUp).Row
lastrow1 = wsO.Cells(Rows.Count, 4).End(xlUp).Row

 With wsO
        For iCounter1 = 2 To lastrow
        If wsO.Cells(iCounter1, 9) > 120 Then

        wsO.Cells(iCounter1, 9).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 101, 101)

        ElseIf wsO.Cells(iCounter1, 9) > 0 And wsO.Cells(iCounter1, 9) < 120 Then

        wsO.Cells(iCounter1, 9).Interior.Color = RGB(169, 208, 142)

        End If
        Next iCounter1

        With wsO
        For iCounter2 = 2 To lastrow

         If Not IsNumeric(Cells(iCounter2, 9)) Then
         wsO.Cells(iCounter2, 9).EntireRow.Delete
         End If

        Next iCounter2


        Rows("2:200").RowHeight = 30
        End With
        End With
```

Comment: When deleting rows, always loop backwards, so your for loop is `For iCounter2 =  lastrow to 2 step -1`.  as you are deleting rows rows that have not been evaluated are replacing the one deleted.  This row is being skipped.

Comment: Just a quick note, I'd add the worksheet in on this line too: `If Not IsNumeric(Cells(iCounter2, 9)) Then` ...so, it'd be `If Not IsNumeric(wsO.Cells(iCounter2, 9)) Then ...`  and also at the end, specify which worksheet you want to use with `Rows("2:200").RowHeight = 30`.

Comment: [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33744149/code-in-vba-loops-and-never-ends-how-to-fix-this) are some great answers as to how to do what you want.  There are three different approaches.

Comment: thanks @ScottCraner, code works now cheers!

Comment: forgot to reference sheet here  `If Not IsNumeric(Cells(iCounter2, 9))` ,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There seem to be two problems with your code. The primary issue of skipping some rows that should be deleted can be cleared up by looping from the bottom to the top. Failing to work in ths manner may mean that a row is skipped after a row is deleted, the rows are renumbered and you increment on to the next row.

There is a secondary issue where you have implemented a [With ... End With statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wc500chb.aspx) that references the worksheet to be acted upon and then either reiterate the worksheet reference when referencing cells/ranges/rows or discard it altogether.

```
With wsO
    For iCounter1 = 2 To LastRow
        If .Cells(iCounter1, 9) > 120 Then
            .Cells(iCounter1, 9).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 101, 101)
        ElseIf .Cells(iCounter1, 9) > 0 And .Cells(iCounter1, 9) < 120 Then
            .Cells(iCounter1, 9).Interior.Color = RGB(169, 208, 142)
        End If
    Next iCounter1

    'this is the primary change
    'loop from the bottom to the top when deleting rows
    For iCounter2 = LastRow To 2 Step -1
        If Not IsNumeric(.Cells(iCounter2, 9)) Then
            .Cells(iCounter2, 9).EntireRow.Delete
        End If
    Next iCounter2

    .Rows("2:200").RowHeight = 30
End With
```

Note that `Cells` becomes `.Cells` and `Rows` become `.Rows`. The period (aka `.` or *full stop*`) prefix associates each cell/range/row with the parent worksheet referenced in the With ... End With block.

---

¹ <sub>Thanks to [Scott Craner](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4851590/scott-craner) for noting the bottom-to-top method in comments.</sub>

Comment: Never knew vba detects automatically, that it needs to count backwards, if the starting value is smaller than the end value!

Comment: @MarcoGetrost - Thanks for catching that! I've either got to pay better attention or actually run through the code I write.