# VBA delete rows

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to write a VBA code for excel that deletes rows based on the contents of certain cells (all in the same column). My program right now looks like this:

```
Sub removeCol()
Dim i As Integer
i = 1
Do While i < 10
If (Cells(i, 2).Text = "a") Then
Rows(i).Delete
i = i + 1
Else
i = i + 1
End If
Loop
End Sub
```

I would be very grateful for any tips! Right now this thing is not having any affect at all.

Comment: first: you have to go from the bottom of the list to the top. Imagine you have two "a" in row 5 and in row 6. When you go top down you will first find row 5 and delete it. As a result of that all rows will be moved one to the top ... so row 6 will become new row 5. But in the next loop you check new row 6 (which was row 7 before first delete). You see?

Comment: second - not so important - it's better to use For-Next in case that you have a counter in the loop.

Comment: [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33744149/code-in-vba-loops-and-never-ends-how-to-fix-this) is a myriad of ways to accomplish this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Sub removeCol()
    Dim i As Integer

    For i = 10 To 1 Step -1
        If Cells(i, 2) = "a" Then
            Rows(i).Delete
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you! I'm not sure I properly up-liked your post, but this was very useful

Comment: You may wish to [LCase](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg264497.aspx) the comparison as in `If LCase(Cells(i, 2).Value2) = "a" Then`. It is currently case sensitive.

Answer (score 2):

one of the variants is:

```
Sub test()
    Dim i&, x&
    i = [B:B].Cells.Find("*", , , xlByRows, , xlPrevious).Row 'get last row in "B" column
    For x = i To 1 Step -1
        If LCase(Cells(x, 2).Value2) = "a" Then Rows(x).Delete 'Lcase to remove case sensivity, due to "a" not equal to "A"
    Next x
End Sub
```

if you want check cells contents using contains method, then you can use this:

```
Sub test2()
    Dim i&, x&
    i = [B:B].Cells.Find("*", , , xlByRows, , xlPrevious).Row
    For x = i To 1 Step -1
        If LCase(Cells(x, 2).Value2) Like "*a*" Then Rows(x).Delete
    Next x
End Sub
```

or this:

```
Sub test3()
    Dim i&, x&
    i = [B:B].Cells.Find("*", , , xlByRows, , xlPrevious).Row
    For x = i To 1 Step -1
        If InStr(1, Cells(x, 2).Value2, "a", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then Rows(x).Delete
    Next x
End Sub
```