# Find function skips next row

Tags: excel, vba, find

I have stuck with quite odd bug(?) using Find function. For some reason, it can't find next row (n+1), although, it finds any other row in determined range.

```
Sub band()
Dim laik As String
Dim row1 As Integer
Dim DbSh As Worksheet
Set DbSh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
eil = 9 'row in sheet
On Error Resume Next
Do While DbSh.Cells(eil, 1).Value <> ""
  laik = DbSh.Cells(eil, 3).Value
  row1 = DbSh.Range("C" & eil + 1 & ":C1000").Find(laik, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole).row
  If Err.Number <> 0 Then Err.Number = 0: GoTo next1
  If DbSh.Cells(eil, 4).Value = DbSh.Cells(row1, 4).Value And DbSh.Cells(eil, 6).Value = DbSh.Cells(row1, 6).Value And DbSh.Cells(eil, 8).Value = DbSh.Cells(row1, 8).Value Then
    DbSh.Cells(eil, 5).Value = DbSh.Cells(eil, 5).Value & ", " & DbSh.Cells(row1, 5).Value
    DbSh.Range(row1 & ":" & row1).EntireRow.Delete
    eil = eil - 1 'subtract, still looking for more same values
  End If
next1:
  eil = eil + 1
  Loop
End Sub
```

Basically, it looks for same values of cells(eil,3) and if it meets some criteria in D, F and H columns, found row is added to "eil" row (E column) and then it is deleted. If same values in C column are next to each other (eil and eil + 1),

```
row1 = DbSh.Range("C" & eil + 1 & ":C1000").Find(laik, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole).row
```

finds the second available row (from eil+2, eil+3, etc.), skipping eil+1 row. If I remove +1 from Range("C" & eil + 1 & ":C1000"), leaving just Range("C" & eil & ":C1000"), it finds the same row. 
For now, I have a workaround, but it could be cool to find out why "Find" skips the following row.

Comment: I would also suggest to see how you you delete rows (might be one cause for this behaviour). The general way to delete rows is to start from the last row and go upward to the first row. A starting point could be the discussion in the post [VBA delete rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34108043/vba-delete-rows)

Answer (score 0):

The eil = eil + 1 is always adding 1 to eil. DbSh.Range("C" & eil + 1 & ":C1000").Find is also adding 1. Put together, you are skipping over the 'next' row whenever you find something.

This should rectify the issue.

```
...
row1 = DbSh.Range("C" & eil & ":C1000").Find(laik, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole).row
...
```

fwiw, I wouold recommend skipping all that 'controlled error' and use a Find/FindNext pair.

Comment: As I mentioned, when I remove +1 from "Find" function, it finds me the same row. If I take eil = 9, then find range will be C9:C1000. Since value "laik" is from C9, "Find" will find 9th row. Adding +1 to that fuction, I indicate, that "Find" must look in "C10:C1000" range, skipping C9 (and so on). eil = eil +1 comes later and is used only for a cycle. Deleted rows shouldn't cause any problems, because it deletes future rows, not the present one