# Excel VBA Object Required Error at run-time

Tags: excel, vba

I am very new to VBA and just beginning to learn. I have a code here to match all the cells of the "M" column in Sheet1 and Sheet3, and delete all the rows from Sheet1 that contain any value from Sheet3's "M" column.
If I go through it using F8, I do not get any error but when I assign it to a button, it fails at run-time with 'Object Required' error. I tried a few things that I found online, but none of them seem to work.
Below is my code. Any help would be much appreciated.

```
Sub DeleteRows()

    Dim rng As Range
    Dim rng2 As Range
    Dim cell As Object
    Dim cell2 As Object

    Set rng = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("M2:M1541")
    Set rng2 = Sheets("Sheet3").Range("M2:M30")

    For Each cell In rng
        For Each cell2 In rng2
            If cell.Value = cell2.Value Then
                cell.EntireRow.Delete
            End If
        Next
    Next
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You're altering the `Range` that you're iterating over.

Comment: You also want `Application.ScreenUpdating = True` at the end, not `False`.

Comment: Thanks @BigBen I have updated it.

Comment: @Comintern Yes. Could you please suggest what needs to be done?

Comment: May Please try to loop from lower end to upper end of the range in sheet1

Comment: Why set it to true, when you never set it to false in the first place? There is a misconception that you need to set screenupdating back to true, it automatically sets itself back to true when the sub is over.

Comment: When you delete something you should go [backwards](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34108043/vba-delete-rows) since you are changing your original range.

Comment: @AhmedAU That worked! Thank you so much!

Comment: @Davesexcel Noted! Thanks!

Comment: @Wizhi I'll keep that in mind, and that worked! Thank you so much!

Comment: Np, and good luck with your project :)!

Answer (score 1):

You can loop through the cells in sheet2 and filter for those items in sheet1.
Then you would  not be double looping.

```
Sub Button1_Click()
    Dim ws As Worksheet, sh As Worksheet
    Dim LstRw As Long, Rng As Range, Frng As Range, c As Range, Nrng As Range

    Set ws = Sheets("Sheet2")
    Set sh = Sheets("Sheet1")

    With ws
        LstRw = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "M").End(xlUp).Row
        Set Rng = .Range("M2:M" & LstRw)
    End With

    With sh
        Set Frng = .Range("M2:M" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, "M").End(xlUp).Row)
        For Each c In Rng.Cells
            .Range("M1").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=c

            On Error Resume Next
            Set Nrng = Frng.SpecialCells(xlVisible)
            On Error GoTo 0
            If Nrng Is Nothing Then
            Else
                Frng.EntireRow.Delete
            End If
        Next c
        .AutoFilterMode = False
    End With

End Sub
```