# Reset a for loop when a condition is met vba

Tags: excel, vba

I want to reset a counter in a loop every time a condition is met.

Here my code :

```
Set report = Workbooks("Rapports").Worksheets("Relevé_" & Client &  "_" & Datereport2)
For i = 1 To 11 'pas auto
    VM1 = report.Range("G" & i + 11).Value
    VM2 = report.Range("H" & i + 11).Value
     If VM1 = 0 And VM2 = 0 Then
     report.Rows(i + 11 & ":" & i + 11).Delete
     End If

     Next
end sub
```

When the row is deleted i want to restart i at 1, until no more cell = 0.
Also, i dont want to delete rows where there is an empty cell.

Thank you !!

Comment: For other ways to do this see [HERE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33744149/code-in-vba-loops-and-never-ends-how-to-fix-this)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two changes:

```
Set report = Workbooks("Rapports").Worksheets("Relevé_" & Client & "_" & Datereport2)
For i = 11 To 1 Step -1 'pas auto
    VM1 = report.Range("G" & i + 11).Value
    VM2 = report.Range("H" & i + 11).Value
     If VM1 = "0" And VM2 = "0" Then
     report.Rows(i + 11 & ":" & i + 11).Delete
     End If

     Next
End Sub
```

1. Loop backwards. This will take care of any duplicates and will not need to run more than once.
2. change `0` to `"0"`  This will force it to find `0` and not empty cells.