# Reset the loop when the condition is met excel vba

Tags: excel, vba

I have an excel sheet. I want to reset the loop when the condition is met as I have two conditions. However, I thought of implementing step next to the for loop from this solution website, [Reset a for loop when a condition is met vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35047024/reset-a-for-loop-when-a-condition-is-met-vba). It did not work as it applied to only numbers not A1. What is the solutions to correct this problem? Thank you.

```
Sub run()
 Set MR = Range("A1:Q1")
    'Loop through the cell in the first row
    For Each cell In MR
        If cell.Value = "First Discovered" Or cell.Value = "Last Observed" Then cell.EntireColumn.Delete
    Next cell
End Sub
```

Comment: I thought the solution was to only reset the loop when the condition is met. I should expand my mind to find other solutions. Thank for the great solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You **do not** need to reset the loop if you want to look in Columns `A:Q` in the first row. The key is to avoid deleting while you are inside the loop since this creates shifts in the range you are looping through.

The below solution will loop through your range and add target cells to a `Union` (collection of cells) and once the loop is complete, it will delete the columns of all cells in the `Union`

---

### Also,

Add `Option Explicit`. You need to declare your variables and `Option Explicit` will force you to do so. This also indirectly acts as a handy spell checker.

Last thing: I changed your variable '`cell`' to '`myCell`' to avoid confusion with the already existing object `Cells`

---

```
Option Explicit

Sub run()

Dim MR As Range, myCell As Range, DeleteMe As Range

Set MR = Range("A1:Q1")

For Each myCell In MR
    If myCell = "First Discovered" Or myCell = "Last Observed" Then
        If DeleteMe Is Nothing Then
            Set DeleteMe = myCell
        Else
            Set DeleteMe = Union(DeleteMe, myCell)
        End If
    End If
Next myCell

If Not DeleteMe Is Nothing Then DeleteMe.EntireColumn.Delete

End Sub
```