# Excel Macro Loop Delete

Tags: excel, vba, loops, macros

I can't seems make my loop work:

```
For Each c In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("appointments").Range("N1:N1000000")
     If c = "Test" Then c.EntireRow.Delete
Next
```

What I want is to delete rows with cell value of Test in Column N.

Comment: Change to a regular for loop and loop backwards. There are many examples on this site and others.

Comment: I'm sorry I'm new to this.  Can you help me edit it?

Comment: See [HERE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33744149/code-in-vba-loops-and-never-ends-how-to-fix-this)  It gives three good methods to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Dim i As Long

For i = 1000000 To 1 Step -1
    If Cells(i, 14).Value = "Test" Then
        Rows(i).Delete
    End If
Next i
```

The above will do what you requested, however I would recommend something like this as I'm doubting you have a million rows worth of data:

```
Dim i As Long
Dim LastRow As Long

LastRow = ActiveCell.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row

For i = LastRow To 1 Step -1
    If Cells(i, 14).Value = "Test" Then
        Rows(i).Delete
    End If
Next i
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's my answer and it works fast:

```
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("appointments").Range("N1:N1000000").AutoFilter 1, "=Test"
     ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("appointments").Range("N2:N1000000").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete
     ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("appointments").AutoFilterMode = False
```