# Macro required to delete rows based on cell in Column A being empty (but not quite)

Tags: excel, vba

Newbie here, and struggling with how Excel defines a cell to be empty... I have a macro that does the following;

-Creates a worksheet in the existing worksheet called "Export_Odds"
-Copies data in range A1:M52 from existing worksheet ("Odds")
-Paste special (values only) into the newly generated worksheet ("Export_Odds")

It should then run through the A column of the pasted data and for every row where Column A is empty it should delete the entire row.

The problem seems to be that every cell in column A from the original worksheet ("Odds") has a formula which is an IF statement returning "".

Because of this Excel doesn't appear to believe that any of the cells in column A on the new sheet ("Export_Odds") is indeed empty - I believe this to be called a "null string"?. So even if the cell in column A looks empty the macro won't delete any of them.

A work around would be mega. So far it looks like:

```
'Create Worksheet
Worksheets.Add(After:=Worksheets(1)).Name = "Export_Odds"

'Copy and paste date to new worksheet
Sheets("Odds").Range("A1:M52").Copy
Sheets("Export_Odds").Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

'Delete entire row if cell in Column A is empty
On Error Resume Next
Columns("A").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Delete
```

Comment: Test for `len` of cell instead and delete that way?

Comment: [HERE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33744149/code-in-vba-loops-and-never-ends-how-to-fix-this).  This shows three ways to do what you want.

Comment: You can also just say if the cell value = vbNullString then delete the row

Comment: Agree with other posts here but be mindful that if you loop on some collection of rows and delete a row Excel will still think you have the original number of rows & things get... well messy. You want something like this - dim lastRow as integer lastRow = range("A100000").end.(xlup).row For x = lastRow to 1 step - 1 if cells(x,1) = "" then rows(x).delete. The key here is to loop backwards.

Comment: Thanks all. I ended up adding a row that counted LEN() and when this =0 then it got deleted. cheers