# VBA Conditional Formatting + Delete cells

Tags: vba, excel

Is there a method to delete a whole row based upon a cell in it using VBA?

Trying to complete the following task:

1. Select whole row based upon a cell in it in my case cell value <3
2. Delete entire row

I used CF to achieve the first part, but when trying to delete the highlighted cells (color from CF), the color cannot be found by the Find Function.

Can anyone redirect me to a specific post please been looking for hours.
Danke

Comment: See [HERE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33744149/code-in-vba-loops-and-never-ends-how-to-fix-this)  and instead of looking for the color just look at the cell in the row and test if <3.

Comment: Thank you, gonna give it a try right away

Comment: Scott it aint going to work because:
For e.g
ColumnA= Name, ColumnB= points
the goal is to select data from ColumnB, if is less than 3, delete both ColumnA&ColumnB.
In the post you suggested, the selection is not extended to entire row (taking into account all columns)

Comment: All three methods delete the entire row.  You would simply change the if statements to look at column B and see if it is less than 3.  It will then delete the entire row.

Comment: O my bad should have tried harder... ty Scott will give VBA Pete s code a try first, then will double check that post again.

Comment: Scott I have a question for you.
Let's say that the rows that i would like to delete are found within Column A to E. The code below seams to work fine, but if does delete all the data  in G to H *F is a blank space which means not connected to any data in A to E.



code:
With Worksheets("Sheet1")
     'assumes row 1 is headers
     .Range("A2:A90").AutoFilter 1, "<3"
     .Range("A2:A90").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete
     .AutoFilterMode = False
End With

Comment: That is a new question.  Ask it in another post with the new code.  I do not have time to test at the moment and someone else may be able to answer quicker.

Comment: ok. ty will do ty :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about something like this:

```
Sub Delete3()

Dim F As Integer
Dim Y As Integer
Dim RngCount As Range


Set RngCount = ActiveSheet.Range("COLUMN:COLUMN")
Y = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(RngCount)

For F = Y To 1 Step -1

If ActiveSheet.Range("COLUMN" & F).Value < 3 Then
ActiveSheet.Rows(F).EntireRow.Delete
End If

Next F

End Sub
```

You just need to replace the word COLUMN with the letter of the column where the values are, e.g. "C:C" and "C".

Comment: Thank you #VBAP, something is missing though, well none of these formulas (either the link provided by Scott) are working as i would need them to.
Think am a newbie that s why.
Will try all them again

Comment: that was quick, let me give that a try

Comment: yeah in fact it was the Next function.
VBA P, thank you so much for your help, one last thing:
can i limit the columns ? I dont want to delete the entire rows found within all the columns of the worksheet just A&B for instance.

Comment: Yes, replacing ActiveSheet.Rows(F).EntireRow.Delete with ActiveSheet.Range("A" & F & ":B" & F).Delete should do the trick.

Comment: Not a problem Enrik. Please don't forget to check my response as the answer to your question.