# Using Countif in Excel to delete rows

Tags: vba, excel

From what I see in other related questions on the countif function, I do not see why my code is not working.

I have a field where I have identified rows I want to delete to contain the value "GO AWAY". Following is the code I am using to make them go away.
DF is my current worksheet as defined by 'Set DF = CWB.Worksheets("Delete")' and 'Set CWB = ThisWorkbook'.

```
Dim iVal As Integer
Dim LastRow2 As Long
Dim ii As Integer    

Do While (iVal > 0)
        LastRow2 = DF.Cells(DF.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        iVal = DF.Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(DF.Range("d:d"), "GO AWAY")

        For ii = 2 To LastRow2
            If DF.Cells(ii, 4).Value = "GO AWAY" Then
                Rows(ii).EntireRow.Select
                DF.Cells.EntireRow.Select  'Caution to testers.  This line and the next will delete the entire worksheet.
                Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp   'Caution to testers.  This line and the previous will delete the entire worksheet.
            End If
        Next ii
    Loop
```

If I use the formula in a random cell:

```
=CountIf(D:D, "GO AWAY")
```

returns 128.

Comment: Oh, you need to put your `WHILE` at the end!  Since you don't declare the `ival` it will end the `do` right away

Comment: There are better ways to delete rows see the answers here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33744149/code-in-vba-loops-and-never-ends-how-to-fix-this

Comment: @ScottCraner Doesn't this code: `DF.Cells.EntireRow.Select Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp` Delete the entire sheet?

Comment: @Chrismas007 I would think so.

Comment: The reason it would delete them all on the first pass is because when you delete a line it shifts up.  So if ii = 10 and we delete that row, what was row 11 becomes row 10, and as ii iterates to 11 we skip the row that was 11 and is now 10.  So by iterating backwards we do not have that problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@DavidCampbell Because your `ival` variable was not defined, it was defaulting to null or zero in some cases.  That satisfied your condition of ending the `Do While (ival > 0)`.  Since `ival` was less than 0, it ended the whole `Do` Loop.

Much simpler code to delete rows:

```
    LastRow2 = DF.Cells(DF.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    For ii = LastRow2 To 2 Step -1
        If DF.Cells(ii, 4).Value = "GO AWAY" Then
            Rows(ii).EntireRow.Delete xlShiftUp
        End If
    Next ii
```

Comment: @DavidCampbell Because your `ival` variable was not defined, it was defaulting to null or zero in some cases.  That satisfied your condition of ending the `Do While (ival > 0)`.  Since `ival` was less than 0, it ended the whole `Do` Loop.