# Rewriting VBA For loop more efficiently and faster

Tags: vba, excel

I have written the following program below which takes in a start date and an end date from the user within cells 2D & 2E. The program will iterated through the rows backwards, deleting the rows where the criteria is not being met. How else could I guide my code to be more efficient and operate faster overall? Any rule of thumbs to speed things up? It currently will process 1164 items within 45 seconds on my machine.

```
Sub SpecialDates()

Dim n As Long, i As Long, j As Long, date1 As Date, date2 As Date, date3 As Long, startDate As Date, endDate As Date

n = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
j = 4

For i = n To 4 Step -1
    j = j + 1
    startDate = Cells(2, "D").Value
    endDate = Cells(2, "E").Value

    If Not IsEmpty(Cells(i, "AB").Value) And Not IsEmpty(Cells(i, "AE").Value) Then
        If Cells(i, "AE").Value >= startDate And Cells(i, "AE").Value <= endDate Then
            date1 = Cells(i, "AB").Value 'AB=Entry Date
            date2 = Cells(i, "AE").Value 'AE=Rec'd 'PRIMARY CHECKING DATE'
            date3 = Work_Days(date2, date1)
            If date3 >= 0 Then
                Cells(i, "BG").Value = date3
            Else
                Rows(i).EntireRow.Delete
            End If
        Else
            Rows(i).EntireRow.Delete
        End If
    Else
        Rows(i).EntireRow.Delete
    End If
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: If the codes works and you want a review then you should be on codereview and not here.

Comment: @ScottCraner can you please provide me a link? Thank you for the tip!

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Josh are you using `Application.ScreenUpdating = False` , `Application.EnableEvents = False` and `Application.DisplayAlerts = False` ? to fasten your loop

Comment: @ShaiRado I am not. I will be sure to look into these and apply them into my code. Thank you for the tip!

Comment: @ShaiRado Can you please submit this as an answer so I can reward you? You helped increase my code speed from 1,000 results in 45 seconds to 25,000 results in 1 minute! Much appreciated!

Comment: @Josh it's ok, you can still reduce it by at least 50%, take the lines `j = j + 1` and `startDate = Cells(2, "D").Value` and `endDate = Cells(2, "E").Value` out of the loop since you don't advance them inside the loop. Also, you can accumulate an array of numbers of rows to delete, and then delete them at once.

Answer (score 0):

If you're willing to trade off readability for performance then give it a try to my code:

```
Sub SpecialDates()

Dim n As Long, i As Long, j As Long, k As Long, Date1 As Date, Date2 As Date, Date3 As Long, StartDate As Date, EndDate As Date
Dim DataRow As Collection

Set DataRow = New Collection                        'Storage for the row address which will be deleted
n = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
StartDate = Cells(2, 4)
EndDate = Cells(2, 5)
DataDate1 = Range(Cells(4, 28), Cells(n, 28))
DataDate2 = Range(Cells(4, 31), Cells(n, 31))
ReDim DataDate3(1 To UBound(DataDate1), 1 To 1)

For i = LBound(DataDate1) To UBound(DataDate1)
    If DataDate1 <> vbNullString Then
        If DataDate2 <> vbNullString Then
            If DataBase2(i, 1) >= StartDate Then
                If DataBase2(i, 1) <= EndDate Then
                    Date1 = DataDate1(i, 1)
                    Date2 = DataDate2(i, 1)
                    Date3 = Work_Days(Date2, Date1)

                    If Date3 >= 0 Then
                        DataDate3(i, 1) = Date3
                    Else
                        DataRow.Add i + 3           'Store the row address which will be deleted
                    End If
                Else
                    DataRow.Add i + 3               'Store the row address which will be deleted
                End If
            End If
        Else
            DataRow.Add i + 3                       'Store the row address which will be deleted
        End If
    End If
Next

Cells(4, 59).Resize(UBound(DataDate1), 1) = DataDate3

For k = 1 To DataRow.Count Step -1
    Rows(DataRow(k)).EntireRow.Delete
Next

End Sub
```

**TIPS:**

To obtain a better performance try the following tips:

1. Use a number index instead of an index involving string. So `Cells(2, 4)` is faster than `Cells(2, "D")`. For further info, see [Are these novelty ways [and possibly the best way?] to refer a dynamic cell in VBA?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38770437/3397819).
2. Nested IF statements is considered faster than IF statement with logical statements.
3. Working in arrays is faster than working in the range of cells.
4. Try to use `Application.ScreenUpdating = False`, `Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual` and `Application.DisplayAlerts = False` to speed things up. Just be sure to put `Application.ScreenUpdating = True`, `Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic` and `Application.DisplayAlerts = True` at the end.
5. Alternatively, you might use **AutoFilter** to delete rows faster than use a loop statement. You might be interested in seeing this: [Deleting entire row on criteria cannot handle 400,000 rows](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38630653/3397819).