# Excel VBA deleting rows based on an if statement (speed up)

Tags: excel, vba

I am deleting rows based on the value in column P.
Cells in column P have an if statement: IF(K<10,0,1)

If the value in column P is 0, then the row needs to be deleted. 
I am using the following macro which works but takes quite long. 
I would like to beable to process about 10000 rows.

It would be much appreciated if I could have some suggestions on speeding up this code.

[I had tried using this if statement: IF(K<10,"",1)
And then deleting rows using SpecialCells(XlCellTypeBlanks) but the the cells are not interpreted as blank , due to the presence of the formula I presume. ]

```
 Sub RemoveBlankRows()

   Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    'PURPOSE: Deletes any row with 0 cells located inside P
    'Reference: www.TheSpreadsheetGuru.com

   Dim rng As Range
   Dim blankrng As Range
   Dim cell As Range

   'Store blank cells inside a variable
   'On Error GoTo NoBlanksFound
Set rng = Range("P2:P30000") '.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)
'On Error GoTo 0

For Each cell In rng
If cell.Value = 0 Then
    cell.EntireRow.Delete
    'Value = ""
End If
Next

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33744149/code-in-vba-loops-and-never-ends-how-to-fix-this

Comment: What about sorting? Can you sort your table/data, in a way that groups your `0` cells together, then just grab the first row and last row with a `0`, and delete the range?

Answer (score 0):

This looks for ***0*** and avoids blanks:

```
Sub RowKiller()
    Dim rKill As Range, r As Range, rng As Range

    Set rng = Range("P2:P30000")
    Set rKill = Nothing

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    Application.EnableEvents = False

    For Each r In rng
        If r.Value = 0 And r.Value <> "" Then
            If rKill Is Nothing Then
                Set rKill = r
            Else
                Set rKill = Union(rKill, r)
            End If
        End If
    Next r

    If Not rKill Is Nothing Then rKill.EntireRow.Delete

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

This is only demo code.  Tailor it to meet your needs.

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: Works perfectly