# VBA - Moving Rows to different row based on criteria is only working one at a time

Tags: vba, excel, rows

I have created an excel VBA script to move rows to different sheets based on the status of the item in that row. However, when I run the code it does not always move all the items at once if there is more than one status update. I would like to make it so that if multiple rows have status updates, when I run the script they all move at once. I'm assuming it has something to do with the "if statements" but I am drawing a blank on any other ways to do it. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Below is my code:

```
Sub MoveRows()
Dim xRg As Range
Dim xCell As Range
Dim A As Long
Dim B As Long
Dim C As Long
Dim D As Long
A = Worksheets("Tracking").UsedRange.Rows.Count
B = Worksheets("In Progress").UsedRange.Rows.Count
C = Worksheets("Completed").UsedRange.Rows.Count
D = Worksheets("Removed").UsedRange.Rows.Count
If B = 1 Then
   If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Worksheets("In Progress").UsedRange) = 0 Then B = 0
ElseIf C = 1 Then
   If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Worksheets("Completed").UsedRange) = 0 Then C = 0
ElseIf D = 1 Then
   If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Worksheets("Removed").UsedRange) = 0 Then D = 0
    End If
Set xRg = Worksheets("Tracking").Range("S1:S" & A)
On Error Resume Next
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
For Each xCell In xRg
    If CStr(xCell.Value) = "In Progress" Then
        xCell.EntireRow.Copy Destination:=Worksheets("In Progress").Range("A" & B + 1)
        xCell.EntireRow.Delete
        B = B + 1
    ElseIf CStr(xCell.Value) = "Completed" Then
        xCell.EntireRow.Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Completed").Range("A" & C + 1)
        xCell.EntireRow.Delete
        C = C + 1
    ElseIf CStr(xCell.Value) = "Remove" Then
        xCell.EntireRow.Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Removed").Range("A" & D + 1)
        xCell.EntireRow.Delete
        D = D + 1
    End If
Next
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Every time you do a `xCell.EntireRow.Delete` the following row is moved into the current row so, when you go to the next `xCell`, you have not yet processed what is in the current row.  The best way to solve this sort of situation is to either loop from the last row to the first row, or to delete all applicable rows at once **after** the loop is ended.  Have a look at the answers for [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/33744149/6535336).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**edited** to add selected rows deletion

just be sure to have a header row in your "Tracking" worksheet and then `AutoFilter()` will make your life as easy as the following code:

```
Option Explicit

Sub MoveRows()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    With Worksheets("Tracking")
        With .Range("S1", .Cells(.Rows.count, "S").End(xlUp))
            FilterAndCopy .Cells, "In Progress"
            FilterAndCopy .Cells, "Completed"
            FilterAndCopy .Cells, "Remove"
        End With
    End With

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub

Sub FilterAndCopy(rng As Range, filterStrng As String)
    With rng '<--| reference passed 'rng' range
        .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=filterStrng '<--| filter its 1st column with passed 'filterStrng'
        If Application.WorksheetFunction.Subtotal(103, .Resize(, 1)) > 1 Then '<--| if any cell filtered other than header
            With .Resize(.Rows.count).Offset(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow
                .Copy Destination:=Worksheets(filterStrng).Cells(Rows.count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1)  '<--|copy filtered cells (skipping headers row) to passed 'filterStrng' named worksheet 1st column from its column A first empty row after last not empty one
                .Delete
            End With
        End If
        .Parent.AutoFilterMode = False
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks this worked to move the row but once the row is moved I wanted to delete it from the tracking sheet. Where do I add in the line to delete the rows once they're moved?

Comment: See edited code. If this solved your question then please mark answer as accepted. Thank you!

Comment: @gluc7, I saw you already posted this code as part of another question of yours. would you then please mark it as accepted. thank you

Comment: @gluc7; any chance to have a proper feedback from you?