# Why doesn't this delete every row?

Tags: excel, vba

I've found a workaround code for what I am trying to do by filtering and deleting but to better my lack of knowledge in VBA I would like to understand why this macro isn't working as I intend it to.

For this example; I want to identify values of a column that begin with "HH G" and delete that entire row of data.
The macro I came up with does in fact work, but I have to manually repeat it since it will only remove a few rows at a time.

```
Sub test()
Dim c As Range

For Each c In Range("Table19").Columns(5).Cells
If Left(c, 4) = "HH G" Then c.EntireRow.Delete
Next

End Sub
```

Thanks so much in advance.

Comment: You need to loop backwards, see here for many examples: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33744149/code-in-vba-loops-and-never-ends-how-to-fix-this

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Code in VBA loops and never ends. How to fix this?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33744149/code-in-vba-loops-and-never-ends-how-to-fix-this)

Comment: My question was not "why does this continuously loop" but rather why will this **NOT** loop? Therefore I would disagree that this is a duplicate of the supplied thread. If the fix is to loop backward, I thank you but my inquiry is the why, **why** when written as I have it, is it automatically stopping itself after identifying only one or two lines.

Thanks much

Comment: The answers on how to fix your problem are the same.  The problem is: as you loop forward and come to a row to delete the one below becomes the active loop and then it lops and effectively skips that on.  So for example you delete row 10, row 11 becomes row 10 and the loop moves to the new row 11 which was row 12 thus skipping the old row 11.

Comment: Thank you, that is exactly what I wanted to know.