# Removing rows with less than .089 (significant value)

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to write a Macro to delete rows with any values in Column H (AverageWeight) below 0.890.  No matter what I write and try it will just not do anything.  I am no coding expert by any means and just do it form time to time to help with work metrics.  Can someone look at my data and help.  It needs to be As Long because this spreadsheet is uploaded from a database daily.

Codes below:

```
Sub Delete089()
    Dim LastRow As Long, n As Long
    LastRow = Range(H2000000).End(xlUp).Row
    For n = LastRow To 1 Step -1
        If Cells(n, 2).Value <= 0.089 Then Cells(n, 2).EntireRow.Delete
    Next n
End Sub

Sub Delete089()

Dim i As Long

    With Application

        .Calculation = xlCalculationManual

        .ScreenUpdating = False

    For i = Selection.Rows.Count To 1 Step -1

        If WorksheetFunction.CountA(Selection.Rows(i)) < 0.89 Then

            Selection.Rows(i).EntireRow.Delete

        End If

    Next i

        .Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

        .ScreenUpdating = True

    End With

End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a code for me site.  Please post the attempt that got you the closest and tell us were it went wrong and we will help overcome the specific problem.

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33744149/code-in-vba-loops-and-never-ends-how-to-fix-this though the question is not the same, the answers will give you a good starting point.

Comment: I will take a look at that.  I have tried looking all over and unless i am missing something, then I dont know the solution.

Comment: Your first bit of code can't even run as this fails on two counts `Range(H2000000)`. it should be `Range("H" & rows.count)` as there are not 2m rows in a spreadsheet. In the second one, COUNTA only counts the number of non-empty cells, as a quick perusal of Excel Help would tell you. Also why are you checking the last value in H but then checking column B?

Comment: @Kyle, "long" numbers are integers only.  Turning .089 to a long number automatically rounds it up or down to 1 or 0.  I'll try to find the code for you.

Comment: @JohnMuggins - don't think he is turning it into a long?

Comment: Thanks @SJR.  I was just going by his statement "It needs to be As Long because this spreadsheet is uploaded from a database daily" on top.  I probably misunderstood that.

Comment: @JohnMuggins - well I may have misunderstood, we're all in the dark a bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works fine with leaving column H as double precision decimal numbers.  you just forgot to put quotation marks around your "H20000"

Oh wait - Column "H" is column 8 - not column 2. re-edited.  And 2000000 causes an error.  I changed it to 200000.

```
Sub Delete089()
Dim LastRow As Long, n As Long
LastRow = Range("H200000").End(xlUp).Row
For n = LastRow To 1 Step -1
    If Cells(n, 8).Value <= 0.089 Then Cells(n, 1).EntireRow.Delete
Next n

End Sub
```

Comment: I know i left some details out, not on purpose.  Like i mentioned, I do not code too much, so just giving what I knew.  Anyway, thank you very much this code worked just fine.

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub Del089()

    LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 8).End(xlUp).Row

    For x = LastRow To 1 Step -1

        If Cells(x, 8).Value <= 0.089 Then
            Cells(x, 8).EntireRow.Delete
        End If

    Next x

End Sub
```

Assuming we are talking about Column H.