# To delete all rows when condition apply VBA with For and IF

Tags: vba, excel

Excel VBA

I would like to delete all rows based on cond
see if statement 
but the code does not delete all rows that have `ws.Cells(i, 6).Value = 0`

```
Sub Clean()

For Each ws In Worksheets
    ' find Last Row
    LastRow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    ' loop over all rows
    For i = 2 To LastRow ' start of the for loop

        If ws.Cells(i, 6).Value = 0 Then

            Rows(i).Delete

        End If

    Next i

Next ws

End Sub
```

Comment: Look at these answers and comments they tell you why and how to avoid it.  They also give options to speed it up. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33744149/code-in-vba-loops-and-never-ends-how-to-fix-this

Comment: You need to use an indexed `For/Next` and loop backwards instead: `For nIndex = LastRow To 1 Step -1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace

```
 For i = 2 To LastRow
```

with

```
 For i =  LastRow to 2 step -1
```

should work much better.

Comment: This should indeed do the trick but I thought it might help to explain why. When you're iterating from top to bottom, if a row is found to match the criteria and deleted, all of the rows below it will be shifted up one row, which means what was row 30 is now row 29, etc. So, if you had two rows in a row that matched the criteria (say row 29 and 30), and row 29 was deleted, row 30 would become row 29 after row 29 was already checked, so it would be skipped over entirely. By iterating in reverse like this answer suggests, no rows are skipped so you shouldn't have any missed rows.

Answer (score 0):

I found you are missing something important in your code.
When you delete a line, your `i` variable automatically skips 1 line and the current line after line deletion is not being validated.

```
Sub Clean()
  For Each ws In Worksheets
    ' find Last Row
    LastRow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    ' loop over all rows
    For i = 2 To LastRow ' start of the for loop
        If ws.Cells(i, 6).Value = 0 Then
          Rows(i).Delete
          i = i - 1 ' force your code to review the same line again
        End If
   Next i
  Next ws
End Sub
```

Hope it helps.