# Vba code to delete the entire row if value for particular column for that row does not match in another worksheets

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to delete those rows for which values of cells of column A in both worksheet does not match but the given code gives me wrong output and deletes all the data. Kindly help me with the correct version of the code.

```
Lastrowo = ws1.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
Lastrowc = ws2.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row

For x = 1 To Lastrowo
  For m = 1 To Lastrowc  
    If Workbooks("A.xlsx").Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(x, 1).Value <>
    Workbooks("B.xlsx").Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(m, 1).Value Then
      Workbooks("A.xlsx").Sheets("Sheet1").Rows(x).EntireRow.Delete
      Workbooks("B.xlsx").Sheets("Sheet1").Rows(m).EntireRow.Delete
    End If
  Next m
Next x
```

Comment: Is it clear to u , now

Comment: why dont you use the `x` variable also for workbook B? Do you really need the second loop?

Comment: Try flagging your rows for deletion in the loops, and then add another loop to delete all the flagged rows. Deleting as you go is messing up your loops

Comment: If your first worksheet contained values of 1,2,3,4,6 in the first 5 rows of column A, and your second worksheet contained values of 1,3,4,5,6 in the first 5 rows, do you want to (a) remove the 2nd, 3rd and 4th rows from both worksheets, or (b) remove the 2nd row from the first worksheet and the 4th row from the second worksheet?

Comment: I want the option a

Comment: I used 2 loops because my number of record in both worksheets are different so in order to calculate the last row differently using 2 loops

Comment: you dont need the second loop. you only need to determine the max last row from the 2 worksheet and then use the max as a loop cycle limit.

Answer (score 1):

Same code, without the second loop

```
Lastrowo = ws1.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
Lastrowc = ws2.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row

For x = 1 To Lastrowo
    If Workbooks("A.xlsx").Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(x, 1).Value <>
    Workbooks("B.xlsx").Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(x, 1).Value Then
      Workbooks("A.xlsx").Sheets("Sheet1").Rows(x).EntireRow.Delete
      Workbooks("B.xlsx").Sheets("Sheet1").Rows(x).EntireRow.Delete
    End If
Next x
```

I would recommend reversing the loop by going from bottom to top.
`For x = Lastrowo To 1 Step - 1`

See other post dealing with similar code: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47062983/4636801

Comment: I have tried this but did not get the desired results

Comment: @yashikavaish If you change the `For` statement to be `For x = Application.Max(Lastrowo, Lastrowc) To 1 Step -1`, does that give you the desired results?  (Based on your reply to my comment to the question, it should.  So, if it doesn't, please explain what **are** the desired results.)