# If statement skips body when comparing string values VBA

Tags: excel

I'm trying to delete columns based on keywords. The if statement skips the body even when the strings match perfectly and the variable types match. I've added asterisks around the line giving me trouble as well as my watch results. If anyone could give me a reason this is occurring I would greatly appreciate it.

```
Dim sourcebook As Workbook
Dim sourcesheet As Worksheet
Dim lastcol As Long
'Dim currentCell As String



Set sourcebook = ActiveWorkbook
Set sourcesheet = sourcebook.Sheets("Sheet1")

Set ws = Application.activesheet

With ws
    If WorksheetFunction.CountA(Cells) > 0 Then
        lastcol = Cells.Find(what:="*", searchorder:=xlByColumns, searchdirection:=xlPrevious).Column
    End If
End With

Set chkrng = activesheet.Range("E1", Cells(1, lastcol))

'time keywords
t1 = "Min. Time   L1 Phase"
t2 = "Max. TimeL1 Phase"
t3 = "Min. TimeL2 Phase"
t4 = "Max. TimeL2 Phase"
t5 = "Min. TimeL3 Phase"
t6 = "Max. TimeL3 Phase"
t7 = "Min. Time3 Phase Sy..."
t8 = "Max. Time3 Phase Sy..." 

For Each cell In chkrng
    ***If cell.Value = t1 Then cell.EntireColumn.Delete***
Next
Watch :   :cell.Value : "Min. Time   L1 Phase" : Variant/String 
Watch :   :t1 : "Min. Time   L1 Phase" : Variant/String :
```

Update: I wasn't able to fix the original code but ill attach what I did instead just in case someone else runs into a similar problem.

```
For i = 4 To lastcol - 1
    CurrValue = Range("A1").Offset(0, i).Value
    If InStr(1, CurrValue, "Time") > 0 Then
        Columns(i + 1).Delete
    End If
Next i
```

Comment: When deleting rows one should loop backwards or create a disjointed range using Union.  See [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33744149/code-in-vba-loops-and-never-ends-how-to-fix-this).  Don't get caught up in the actual question, it is not the same but this shows three different methods to delete rows.

Comment: This is a data question rather than a code issue. You just need to check each character of the data.

Comment: I tried counting backwards as suggested and the issue persisted. I added my attempted fix below '    For i = lastcol To 5 Step -1
'        Set currentCell = sourcesheet.Cells(1, i)
'        If currentCell.Value = t1 Then
'            currentCell.EntireColumn.Delete
'        End If
'    Next i   After adding the watch it shows that the statement is returning a false value. I checked each character of cell.value against t1 and they are letter for letter the same word. I have no idea why this isn't working.

Comment: Does `Len(cell.Value) = Len(t1)` show true in watches?

Comment: Yes it does. Anything else I could try?

Comment: a) `Len(cell.Value) = Len(t1)` is true b) `cell.Value = t1` is false c) you have compared each char using `Mid` function - this means there is a bug in VBA, but it is more likely that you made some mistake in one of the steps. I do not think you can get any more help unless you create and share a sample workbook with only the column headers and your code showing how to reproduce the _bug_