# Remove empty rows in huge data set

Tags: excel, vba

I have about 30000 rows that contain just 8000 records. I need to delete the blank rows (22000) between these records.

This code is too slow.

```
Do While True
    If IsEmpty(Cells(j, 1)) Then
        Rows(j).Delete
    ElseIf True Then
        j = j + 1
    End If
Loop
```

Comment: Just sort the data, it will shove the empty rows to the bottom.

Comment: If you looking into a VBA solution than NEVER delete rows top to bottom. Iterate backwards!

Comment: See [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33744149/code-in-vba-loops-and-never-ends-how-to-fix-this)

Comment: You have to iterate backward (from the end to the beginning).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest NOT writing VBA to solve this problem, and instead adding a filter to your data, filtering to blank rows, delete them, and then clear the filter. If you insist on doing this with VBA, then you need to make the following changes:

1. Iterate backwards over the data (from the bottom of the worksheet to the top). This is because as you delete rows, the row numbers shift.
2. Turn off screen updating and calculations. This will make a **HUGE** difference.

Here's an example of the code:

```
Sub RemoveBlankRows()

    'Add performance improvements
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

    'Get last row of worksheet that contains data (based on column 1)
    iLastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    'Iterate through rows
    For i = iLastRow To 1 Step -1
        If IsEmpty(Cells(i, 1)) Then
            Rows(i).Delete
        End If
    Next i

    'Remove Performance Optimizations
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

End Sub
```