# look up cell value in range and if not found delete row. taking 120+ minutes to run

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following code but due to the fact that the sheet I'm processing has 190,000 rows of data it is taking 120+ minutes to process all of it:

Start With

```
Sub Import_Data()

    Start_Import "WIR-Deploy"

End Sub
```

Then this is where I set everything:

```
Option Explicit
Public WB1 As Workbook
Public WS1 As Worksheet
Public WS2 As Worksheet
Public updateSuccess As Boolean
Sub Start_Import(strApp As String)
    Dim WS3 As Worksheet
    Dim importFile As String

    Set WB1 = ThisWorkbook

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Set WS1 = WB1.Sheets("Master Sheet")

    If strApp = "WIR-Deploy" Then
        Set WS2 = WB1.Sheets("RawWhoIsReady-Deploy@8Jul")
        importFile = "H:\99 - Temp\WhoIsReady-Deploy.csv"
        Application.StatusBar = "'Who is ready - Deploy' data Import now runnning..."

    Else
        MsgBox "Not Coded Yet"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    If strApp = "WIR-Deploy" Then
        ImportData strApp, importFile
    Else
        MsgBox "Not Coded Yet"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Application.StatusBar = False

End Sub
```

and then this imports the sheet:

```
Option Explicit
Sub ImportData(strApp, importFile)
    Dim WB2 As Workbook
    Dim WS3 As Worksheet
    Dim lRow, lCol, ImportRow As Long
    Dim rngAsset As Range

    Set WB2 = Workbooks.Open(importFile)

    If strApp = "WIR-Deploy" Then
        WB2.Sheets(1).Copy Before:=WS2
        WB2.Close False
        Set WS3 = WB1.ActiveSheet

        WS3.Columns(1).EntireColumn.Delete
        lRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        lCol = Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    
        With WS3
            .Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("A1"), Order:=xlAscending
            .Sort.SetRange Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(lRow, lCol))
            .Sort.Header = xlYes
            .Sort.Apply
        End With

        For ImportRow = 2 To lRow
            Set rngAsset = WS1.Range("A:A").Find(WS3.Cells(ImportRow, 1))
            If rngAsset Is Nothing Then
                WS3.Rows(ImportRow).EntireRow.Delete
                ImportRow = ImportRow - 1
                lRow = lRow - 1
            End If
    
            Application.StatusBar = "[Deploy Import] " & lRow & " left to process. " & ImportRow & " Retained"
    
            Set rngAsset = Nothing

        Next
    Else
        MsgBox "This has not been coded yet", vbOKOnly + vbCritical
        Exit Sub
    End If

    'WS3.Delete
    WB1.RefreshAll

End Sub
```

Is there anyway I can speed this process up ? A better way to do it? My limited knowledge says that i would struggle to make it any quicker but i'm open to any ideas on making it better

Comment: Make a `Union` Range and delete all the rows at once.  Do not delete one at a time.  i would also use `Application.Match` instead of `Find` as it is a little quicker and makes a difference when looping.

Comment: Show your entire code. I don't see Application.Screenupdating off, variable type declaration ect. You have some problems with not fully qualifying sorting range too.

Comment: You are making a classic mistake.  You are deleting rows in a for loop.  This means that when you delete, for example, row 6, the previous row 7 now becomes row 6 but you loop counter doesn't know this so you will end up skipping over rows.  When deleting rows from a range/collection etc. you should always iterate from the highest index to the lowest index.

Comment: I don't think it is a problem, indexes are searched in every loop here. The main performance problem is pointed by Scott- deleting rows one by one is very slow. Another idea instead union could be add a column to sort range and make columns to delete next to each other, then delete them at once and restore order if necessary

Comment: @ScottCraner I've included the whole code to show what i'm trying

Comment: @madmiddle that does not change what I proposed.  In addition moving the two ranges into variant arrays and looping those will also speed it up.

Comment: @ScottCraner so would you loop through the rows and then use union to delete the collection of rows that don't match ? (never used union)

Comment: Correct.  Delete takes a lot of time.  The fewer done the quicker.  If you use `Union` and delete once, your code will run much quicker.  But it will run even quicker if you iterate a variant array and avoid, referencing the worksheet nearly 400,000 times.

Comment: `Application.StatusBar` also slows things down, so consider only updating that every (eg) 100 rows or so.

Comment: @ScottCraner starting to understand but how do you add to a union that has already been started ?

Comment: see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33744149/code-in-vba-loops-and-never-ends-how-to-fix-this

Comment: @ScottCraner  nearly there, how do i check how many entries are in the union ? (ran out of memory on the PC)

Comment: Try: `rngDel .Areas.Count`

Comment: @ScottCraner shows 1 every time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this:

```
Dim m, rngDel As Range, numDel As Long
'...

numDel = 0
For importrow = lRow To 2 Step -1
    'Match is much faster than Find...
    m = Application.Match(ws3.Cells(importrow, 1).Value, WS1.Range("A:A"), 0)
    
    If IsError(m) Then
        
        numDel = numDel + 1  '<< count rows added
        If rngDel Is Nothing Then
            Set rngDel = ws3.Rows(importrow)
        Else
            Set rngDel = Application.Union(rngDel, ws3.Rows(importrow))
        End If
        
        'delete in batches
        If numDel > 1000 Then
            rngDel.Delete
            Set rngDel = Nothing
            numDel = 0
        End If

    End If
   
    'don't update statusbar too often
    If importrow Mod 1000 = 0 Then
        Application.StatusBar = "On row " & importrow
    End If
Next

'delete last batch of rows
If Not rngDel Is Nothing Then rngDel.Delete
```

You can experiment with deleting rngDel once it gets to a certain size: I recall it can get slower to append new rows once the size gets too large...

Comment: is there a way of counting the entries in the union as i'm struggling to find it