# VBA Autofilter for Criteria IsLetter / any text

Tags: vba, criteria, autofilter

I have a column that I need to filter as part of a sub routine that is free text. I need to filter out all of the cells that contain text of any sort. I am using the vba code

```
    With rng
    .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria:= "cannot find solution - need [A-Za-z]"
    .Offset(1, 0).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1).SpecialCells (xlCellTypeVisible).Rows.Delete
```

The code itself works fine, I just can't workout how to set the criteria to any letter of the alphabet

Is there a way to do this??

Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the same filter via VBA that you can set within Excel, so you should first try to find a filter setting in Excel that fits your need.
When found, remove the filter and record a macro while setting the filter again - that will show you how to set it using VBA.

In your case, I set a custom filter: Click on the filter button on that column, select either "number filters" or "text filters (displayed depending what Excel guesses is the main data type of that column), and select "custom filter".

[image]

There, choose "contains" and enter a `?` as search value.

[image]

If that fits your need, this is the code in VBA:

```
    .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="=*?*", Operator:=xlAnd
```

If this doesn't fit your need because your filter is even more sophisticated, only idea I have is to create a helper column, write a UDF that returns either `True` or `False` depending if the value is to be displayed or not and filter on that helper column instead (you could use regular expressions in that UDF).
Or loop manually over your data and decide in your code which row fits - but be carefull when deleting data, either loop backwards or build a union and delete in one go - plenty of examples for that on SO.

Comment: Thanks @FunThomas. Unfortunately '?' doesn't fit the filter. I have a loop that works but it is thousands of lines of data and it just takes too long amongst the rest of the code that is required to be run so was hoping to find a faster solution. The column is free text and I need the the rows that only contain a 7 digit number but I think the issue is that it is being read as text

Comment: If you need a loop and have a large amount of data: You can dramatically speed up your code by **a)** read all data into an array and loop over that and **b)** build a range variable using the `union`-command and delete all at once - deleting rows is one of the slowest operation in VBA/Excel. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/33744707/7599798 to get an idea